# Main storyboard setting affect rotation function in iOS8

Tags: ios8, autorotate

In my app, the rotation works fine in iOS7 but not working in iOS8.

[image]

As you can see, the status bar rotates, but the view controller does not.

I found the issue is caused by main storyboard setting, but I have no idea why it cased the issue. I just removed main storyboard setting in project file and everything works fine in iOS8.

Following is my codes to load storyboard.

```
[self setMainStoryboard:[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard-ipad" bundle:nil]];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
[self.window setRootViewController:vc];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Maybe I used the wrong way to load storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem, but I think this might not be a good solution. It's just a workaround. Anyway, here is what I have done. If you run into the same problem, you can try removing main storyboard setting in your target.

[image]

That's it, no further steps. Everything is fine after I remove main storyboard setting. Maybe the way I load main storyboard is incorrect or there is something wrong with my setting of storyboard.

Following is the codes I used to load storyboard:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
[self.window setRootViewController:nav];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

If anyone know the correct way to use main storyboard, please give me some feedback. Thanks!